# Percona Mysql kubernetes operator deleting S3 backup files (.md5 and sst_info files) during namespace deletion

Tags: mysql, database, kubernetes, amazon-s3, percona

When I run the percona Mysql kubernetes operator everything works fine even the restoring of backups is fine at first.

The problem is :  The backup files are sent to AWS S3 which contains two folders (full , sst_info) and a .md5 file

All these files are required in order to restore the database. But when the namespace in kubernetes cluster is deleted , the sst_info folder and the .md5 files are being deleted in s3 bucket as well. Which results in not being able to restore the backup afterwards.

[click to view s3 screenshot of backup folders and file before namespace deletion](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xjCFP.png)

[click to view s3 screenshot of backup folders and file after namespace deletion](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G505l.png)

Any help will be appreciated.

percona mysql operator from :  https://github.com/percona/percona-xtradb-cluster-operator

my cr.yaml file:

```html
apiVersion: pxc.percona.com/v1-11-0
kind: PerconaXtraDBCluster
metadata:
  name: cluster1
  finalizers:
    - delete-pxc-pods-in-order
#    - delete-proxysql-pvc
#    - delete-pxc-pvc
#  annotations:
#    percona.com/issue-vault-token: "true"
spec:
  crVersion: 1.11.0
#  secretsName: my-cluster-secrets
#  vaultSecretName: keyring-secret-vault
#  sslSecretName: my-cluster-ssl
#  sslInternalSecretName: my-cluster-ssl-internal
#  logCollectorSecretName: my-log-collector-secrets
#  initImage: percona/percona-xtradb-cluster-operator:1.11.0
#  enableCRValidationWebhook: true
#  tls:
#    SANs:
#      - pxc-1.example.com
#      - pxc-2.example.com
#      - pxc-3.example.com
#    issuerConf:
#      name: special-selfsigned-issuer
#      kind: ClusterIssuer
#      group: cert-manager.io
  allowUnsafeConfigurations: false
#  pause: false
  updateStrategy: SmartUpdate
  upgradeOptions:
    versionServiceEndpoint: https://check.percona.com
    apply: 8.0-recommended
    schedule: "0 4 * * *"
  pxc:
    size: 3
    image: percona/percona-xtradb-cluster:8.0.27-18.1
    autoRecovery: true
#    expose:
#      enabled: true
#      type: LoadBalancer
#      trafficPolicy: Local
#      loadBalancerSourceRanges:
#        - 10.0.0.0/8
#      annotations:
#        networking.gke.io/load-balancer-type: "Internal"
#    replicationChannels:
#    - name: pxc1_to_pxc2
#      isSource: true
#    - name: pxc2_to_pxc1
#      isSource: false
#      configuration:
#        sourceRetryCount: 3
#        sourceConnectRetry: 60
#      sourcesList:
#      - host: 10.95.251.101
#        port: 3306
#        weight: 100
#    schedulerName: mycustom-scheduler
#    readinessDelaySec: 15
#    livenessDelaySec: 600
#    configuration: |
#      [mysqld]
#      wsrep_debug=CLIENT
#      wsrep_provider_options="gcache.size=1G; gcache.recover=yes"
#      [sst]
#      xbstream-opts=--decompress
#      [xtrabackup]
#      compress=lz4
#      for PXC 5.7
#      [xtrabackup]
#      compress
#    imagePullSecrets:
#      - name: private-registry-credentials
#    priorityClassName: high-priority
#    annotations:
#      iam.amazonaws.com/role: role-arn
#    labels:
#      rack: rack-22
#    readinessProbes:
#      initialDelaySeconds: 15
#      timeoutSeconds: 15
#      periodSeconds: 30
#      successThreshold: 1
#      failureThreshold: 5
#    livenessProbes:
#      initialDelaySeconds: 300
#      timeoutSeconds: 5
#      periodSeconds: 10
#      successThreshold: 1
#      failureThreshold: 3
#    containerSecurityContext:
#      privileged: false
#    podSecurityContext:
#      runAsUser: 1001
#      runAsGroup: 1001
#      supplementalGroups: [1001]
#    serviceAccountName: percona-xtradb-cluster-operator-workload
#    imagePullPolicy: Always
#    runtimeClassName: image-rc
#    sidecars:
#    - image: busybox
#      command: ["/bin/sh"]
#      args: ["-c", "while true; do trap 'exit 0' SIGINT SIGTERM SIGQUIT SIGKILL; done;"]
#      name: my-sidecar-1
#      resources:
#        requests:
#          #memory: 100M
#          cpu: 100m
#        limits:
#          #memory: 200M
#          cpu: 200m
#    envVarsSecret: my-env-var-secrets
    #resources:
      #requests:
        #memory: 1G
        #cpu: 600m
#        ephemeral-storage: 1G
#      limits:
#        #memory: 1G
#        cpu: "1"
#        ephemeral-storage: 1G
#    nodeSelector:
#      disktype: ssd
   # affinity:
   #   antiAffinityTopologyKey: "kubernetes.io/hostname"
   #   antiAffinityTopologyKey: "kubernetes.io/hostname"
#      advanced:
#        nodeAffinity:
#          requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
#            nodeSelectorTerms:
#            - matchExpressions:
#              - key: kubernetes.io/e2e-az-name
#                operator: In
#                values:
#                - e2e-az1
#                - e2e-az2
#    tolerations:
#    - key: "node.alpha.kubernetes.io/unreachable"
#      operator: "Exists"
#      effect: "NoExecute"
#      tolerationSeconds: 6000
    podDisruptionBudget:
      maxUnavailable: 1
#      minAvailable: 0
    volumeSpec:
#      emptyDir: {}
#      hostPath:
#        path: /data
#        type: Directory
      persistentVolumeClaim:
#        storageClassName: standard
#        accessModes: [ "ReadWriteOnce" ]
        resources:
          requests:
            storage: 6G
    gracePeriod: 600
  haproxy:
    enabled: true
    size: 3
    image: percona/percona-xtradb-cluster-operator:1.11.0-haproxy
#    replicasServiceEnabled: false
#    imagePullPolicy: Always
#    schedulerName: mycustom-scheduler
#    readinessDelaySec: 15
#    livenessDelaySec: 600
#    configuration: |
#
#    the actual default configuration file can be found here https://github.com/percona/percona-docker/blob/main/haproxy/dockerdir/etc/haproxy/haproxy-global.cfg
#
#      global
#        maxconn 2048
#        external-check
#        insecure-fork-wanted
#        stats socket /etc/haproxy/pxc/haproxy.sock mode 600 expose-fd listeners level admin
#
#      defaults
#        default-server init-addr last,libc,none
#        log global
#        mode tcp
#        retries 10
#        timeout client 28800s
#        timeout connect 100500
#        timeout server 28800s
#
#      frontend galera-in
#        bind *:3309 accept-proxy
#        bind *:3306
#        mode tcp
#        option clitcpka
#        default_backend galera-nodes
#
#      frontend galera-admin-in
#        bind *:33062
#        mode tcp
#        option clitcpka
#        default_backend galera-admin-nodes
#
#      frontend galera-replica-in
#        bind *:3307
#        mode tcp
#        option clitcpka
#        default_backend galera-replica-nodes
#
#      frontend galera-mysqlx-in
#        bind *:33060
#        mode tcp
#        option clitcpka
#        default_backend galera-mysqlx-nodes
#
#      frontend stats
#        bind *:8404
#        mode http
#        option http-use-htx
#        http-request use-service prometheus-exporter if { path /metrics }
#    imagePullSecrets:
#      - name: private-registry-credentials
#    annotations:
#      iam.amazonaws.com/role: role-arn
#    labels:
#      rack: rack-22
#    readinessProbes:
#      initialDelaySeconds: 15
#      timeoutSeconds: 1
#      periodSeconds: 5
#      successThreshold: 1
#      failureThreshold: 3
#    livenessProbes:
#      initialDelaySeconds: 60
#      timeoutSeconds: 5
#      periodSeconds: 30
#      successThreshold: 1
#      failureThreshold: 4
#    serviceType: ClusterIP
#    externalTrafficPolicy: Cluster
#    replicasServiceType: ClusterIP
#    replicasExternalTrafficPolicy: Cluster
#    runtimeClassName: image-rc
#    sidecars:
#    - image: busybox
#      command: ["/bin/sh"]
#      args: ["-c", "while true; do trap 'exit 0' SIGINT SIGTERM SIGQUIT SIGKILL; done;"]
#      name: my-sidecar-1
#      resources:
#        requests:
#          #memory: 100M
#          cpu: 100m
#        limits:
#          #memory: 200M
#          cpu: 200m
#    envVarsSecret: my-env-var-secrets
    #resources:
      #requests:
        #memory: 1G
        #cpu: 600m
#      limits:
#        #memory: 1G
#        cpu: 700m
#    priorityClassName: high-priority
#    nodeSelector:
#      disktype: ssd
#    sidecarResources:
#      requests:
#        #memory: 1G
#        cpu: 500m
#      limits:
#        #memory: 2G
#        cpu: 600m
#    containerSecurityContext:
#      privileged: false
#    podSecurityContext:
#      runAsUser: 1001
#      runAsGroup: 1001
#      supplementalGroups: [1001]
#    serviceAccountName: percona-xtradb-cluster-operator-workload
    affinity:
      antiAffinityTopologyKey: "kubernetes.io/hostname"
#      advanced:
#        nodeAffinity:
#          requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
#            nodeSelectorTerms:
#            - matchExpressions:
#              - key: kubernetes.io/e2e-az-name
#                operator: In
#                values:
#                - e2e-az1
#                - e2e-az2
#    tolerations:
#    - key: "node.alpha.kubernetes.io/unreachable"
#      operator: "Exists"
#      effect: "NoExecute"
#      tolerationSeconds: 6000
    podDisruptionBudget:
      maxUnavailable: 1
#      minAvailable: 0
    gracePeriod: 30
#    loadBalancerSourceRanges:
#      - 10.0.0.0/8
#    serviceAnnotations:
#      service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-backend-protocol: http
#    serviceLabels:
#      rack: rack-23
  proxysql:
    enabled: false
    size: 3
    image: percona/percona-xtradb-cluster-operator:1.11.0-proxysql
#    imagePullPolicy: Always
#    configuration: |
#      datadir="/var/lib/proxysql"
#
#      admin_variables =
#      {
#        admin_credentials="proxyadmin:admin_password"
#        mysql_ifaces="0.0.0.0:6032"
#        refresh_interval=2000
#
#        cluster_username="proxyadmin"
#        cluster_password="admin_password"
#        checksum_admin_variables=false
#        checksum_ldap_variables=false
#        checksum_mysql_variables=false
#        cluster_check_interval_ms=200
#        cluster_check_status_frequency=100
#        cluster_mysql_query_rules_save_to_disk=true
#        cluster_mysql_servers_save_to_disk=true
#        cluster_mysql_users_save_to_disk=true
#        cluster_proxysql_servers_save_to_disk=true
#        cluster_mysql_query_rules_diffs_before_sync=1
#        cluster_mysql_servers_diffs_before_sync=1
#        cluster_mysql_users_diffs_before_sync=1
#        cluster_proxysql_servers_diffs_before_sync=1
#      }
#
#      mysql_variables=
#      {
#        monitor_password="monitor"
#        monitor_galera_healthcheck_interval=1000
#        threads=2
#        max_connections=2048
#        default_query_delay=0
#        default_query_timeout=10000
#        poll_timeout=2000
#        interfaces="0.0.0.0:3306"
#        default_schema="information_schema"
#        stacksize=1048576
#        connect_timeout_server=10000
#        monitor_history=60000
#        monitor_connect_interval=20000
#        monitor_ping_interval=10000
#        ping_timeout_server=200
#        commands_stats=true
#        sessions_sort=true
#        have_ssl=true
#        ssl_p2s_ca="/etc/proxysql/ssl-internal/ca.crt"
#        ssl_p2s_cert="/etc/proxysql/ssl-internal/tls.crt"
#        ssl_p2s_key="/etc/proxysql/ssl-internal/tls.key"
#        ssl_p2s_cipher="ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256"
#      }
#    readinessDelaySec: 15
#    livenessDelaySec: 600
#    schedulerName: mycustom-scheduler
#    imagePullSecrets:
#      - name: private-registry-credentials
#    annotations:
#      iam.amazonaws.com/role: role-arn
#    labels:
#      rack: rack-22
#    serviceType: ClusterIP
#    externalTrafficPolicy: Cluster
#    runtimeClassName: image-rc
#    sidecars:
#    - image: busybox
#      command: ["/bin/sh"]
#      args: ["-c", "while true; do trap 'exit 0' SIGINT SIGTERM SIGQUIT SIGKILL; done;"]
#      name: my-sidecar-1
#      resources:
#        requests:
#          #memory: 100M
#          cpu: 100m
#        limits:
#          #memory: 200M
#          cpu: 200m
#    envVarsSecret: my-env-var-secrets
    #resources:
      #requests:
        #memory: 1G
        #cpu: 600m
#      limits:
#        #memory: 1G
#        cpu: 700m
#    priorityClassName: high-priority
#    nodeSelector:
#      disktype: ssd
#    sidecarResources:
#      requests:
#        #memory: 1G
#        cpu: 500m
#      limits:
#        #memory: 2G
#        cpu: 600m
#    containerSecurityContext:
#      privileged: false
#    podSecurityContext:
#      runAsUser: 1001
#      runAsGroup: 1001
#      supplementalGroups: [1001]
#    serviceAccountName: percona-xtradb-cluster-operator-workload
    affinity:
      antiAffinityTopologyKey: "kubernetes.io/hostname"
#      advanced:
#        nodeAffinity:
#          requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
#            nodeSelectorTerms:
#            - matchExpressions:
#              - key: kubernetes.io/e2e-az-name
#                operator: In
#                values:
#                - e2e-az1
#                - e2e-az2
#    tolerations:
#    - key: "node.alpha.kubernetes.io/unreachable"
#      operator: "Exists"
#      effect: "NoExecute"
#      tolerationSeconds: 6000
    volumeSpec:
#      emptyDir: {}
#      hostPath:
#        path: /data
#        type: Directory
      persistentVolumeClaim:
#        storageClassName: standard
#        accessModes: [ "ReadWriteOnce" ]
        resources:
          requests:
            storage: 2G
    podDisruptionBudget:
      maxUnavailable: 1
#      minAvailable: 0
    gracePeriod: 30
#   loadBalancerSourceRanges:
#     - 10.0.0.0/8
#   serviceAnnotations:
#     service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-backend-protocol: http
#   serviceLabels:
#     rack: rack-23
  logcollector:
    enabled: true
    image: percona/percona-xtradb-cluster-operator:1.11.0-logcollector
#    configuration: |
#      [OUTPUT]
#           Name  es
#           Match *
#           Host  192.168.2.3
#           Port  9200
#           Index my_index
#           Type  my_type
    #resources:
      #requests:
        #memory: 100M
        #cpu: 200m
  pmm:
    enabled: false
    image: percona/pmm-client:2.28.0
    serverHost: monitoring-service
#    serverUser: admin
#    pxcParams: "--disable-tablestats-limit=2000"
#    proxysqlParams: "--custom-labels=CUSTOM-LABELS"
    #resources:
      #requests:
        #memory: 150M
        #cpu: 300m
  backup:
    image: percona/percona-xtradb-cluster-operator:1.11.0-pxc8.0-backup
    backoffLimit: 1
#    serviceAccountName: percona-xtradb-cluster-operator
#    imagePullSecrets:
#      - name: private-registry-credentials
    pitr:
      enabled: true
      storageName: s3-us-west-binlog
      timeBetweenUploads: 60
#      resources:
#        requests:
#          #memory: 0.1G
#          cpu: 100m
#        limits:
#          #memory: 1G
#          cpu: 700m
    storages:
      s3-us-west:
        type: s3
        verifyTLS: true
#        nodeSelector:
#          storage: tape
#          backupWorker: 'True'
#        resources:
#          requests:
#            #memory: 1G
#            cpu: 600m
#        affinity:
#          nodeAffinity:
#            requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
#              nodeSelectorTerms:
#              - matchExpressions:
#                - key: backupWorker
#                  operator: In
#                  values:
#                  - 'True'
#        tolerations:
#          - key: "backupWorker"
#            operator: "Equal"
#            value: "True"
#            effect: "NoSchedule"
#        annotations:
#          testName: scheduled-backup
#        labels:
#          backupWorker: 'True'
#        schedulerName: 'default-scheduler'
#        priorityClassName: 'high-priority'
#        containerSecurityContext:
#          privileged: true
#        podSecurityContext:
#          fsGroup: 1001
#          supplementalGroups: [1001, 1002, 1003]
        s3:
          bucket: abc-percona-mysql-test
          credentialsSecret: my-cluster-name-backup-s3
          region: us-west-1
      s3-us-west-binlog:
        type: s3
        verifyTLS: true
        s3:
          bucket: abc-percona-mysql-test-binlogs
          credentialsSecret: my-cluster-name-backup-s3
          region: us-west-1
      fs-pvc:
        type: filesystem
#        nodeSelector:
#          storage: tape
#          backupWorker: 'True'
#        resources:
#          requests:
#            #memory: 1G
#            cpu: 600m
#        affinity:
#          nodeAffinity:
#            requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
#              nodeSelectorTerms:
#              - matchExpressions:
#                - key: backupWorker
#                  operator: In
#                  values:
#                  - 'True'
#        tolerations:
#          - key: "backupWorker"
#            operator: "Equal"
#            value: "True"
#            effect: "NoSchedule"
#        annotations:
#          testName: scheduled-backup
#        labels:
#          backupWorker: 'True'
#        schedulerName: 'default-scheduler'
#        priorityClassName: 'high-priority'
#        containerSecurityContext:
#          privileged: true
#        podSecurityContext:
#          fsGroup: 1001
#          supplementalGroups: [1001, 1002, 1003]
        volume:
          persistentVolumeClaim:
#            storageClassName: standard
            accessModes: [ "ReadWriteOnce" ]
            resources:
              requests:
                storage: 6G
    schedule:
      - name: "daily-backup-s3"
        schedule: "0/5 * * * *"
        keep: 10
        storageName: s3-us-west
 #     - name: "daily-backup"
 #       schedule: "0 0 * * *"
 #       keep: 5
 #       storageName: fs-pvc
```

my restore.yaml file:

```html
apiVersion: pxc.percona.com/v1
kind: PerconaXtraDBClusterRestore
metadata:
  name: restore1
spec:
  pxcCluster: cluster1
  #backupName: backup1
  #backupName: cron-cluster1-s3-us-west-20226305240-scrvc
  backupSource: #
    destination: s3://osos-percona-mysql-test/cluster1-2022-07-05-11:06:00-full
    s3:
      bucket: osos-percona-mysql-test
      credentialsSecret: my-cluster-name-backup-s3
      region: us-west-1
  pitr:
    type: latest
    date: "2022-07-05 11:10:30"
    backupSource: #
      s3:
        bucket: osos-percona-mysql-test-binlogs
        credentialsSecret: my-cluster-name-backup-s3
        region: us-west-1
```

my operator.yaml file:

```html
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: percona-xtradb-cluster-operator
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app.kubernetes.io/component: operator
      app.kubernetes.io/instance: percona-xtradb-cluster-operator
      app.kubernetes.io/name: percona-xtradb-cluster-operator
      app.kubernetes.io/part-of: percona-xtradb-cluster-operator
  strategy:
    rollingUpdate:
      maxUnavailable: 1
    type: RollingUpdate
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app.kubernetes.io/component: operator
        app.kubernetes.io/instance: percona-xtradb-cluster-operator
        app.kubernetes.io/name: percona-xtradb-cluster-operator
        app.kubernetes.io/part-of: percona-xtradb-cluster-operator
    spec:
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 600
      containers:
      - command:
        - percona-xtradb-cluster-operator
        env:
        - name: WATCH_NAMESPACE
          valueFrom:
            fieldRef:
              apiVersion: v1
              fieldPath: metadata.namespace
        - name: POD_NAME
          valueFrom:
            fieldRef:
              apiVersion: v1
              fieldPath: metadata.name
        - name: OPERATOR_NAME
          value: percona-xtradb-cluster-operator
        image: percona/percona-xtradb-cluster-operator:1.11.0
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        livenessProbe:
          failureThreshold: 3
          httpGet:
            path: /metrics
            port: metrics
            scheme: HTTP
        resources:
          limits:
            cpu: 200m
            memory: 500Mi
          requests:
            cpu: 100m
            memory: 20Mi
        name: percona-xtradb-cluster-operator
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8080
          name: metrics
          protocol: TCP
      serviceAccountName: percona-xtradb-cluster-operator
```

Answer (score 0):

Why are you deleting a namespace? What is the action you're trying to achieve? Are you trying to delete an existing cluster created by the operator?

In that case, I will recommend you use the `kubectl delete` command to delete your cluster like:

```
kubectl delete perconaxtradbcluster/cluster1
```

This will ensure, by design that all the related objects get cleaned up. There is no need to attempt to delete the namespace, since this deletion operation can be invisible to the operator and hence the issue you're seeing.

That is the point of using `operators` to interact with Kubernetes, there is no need for manual action, the operator should provide maintenance utilities out of the box through manipulation of the operator objects :)